cannot run aiohttp test cases using pytest
I am trying to run pytest on my aiohttp application.
I have added a "pytest.ini" config file.
But whenever i run pytest, it simply gives me an error. It never complies my test_file.
My config file looks like this: """ pytest.ini """
[pytest]
addopts = --asyncio

When i run pytest along with this config file, it doesn't allow my code to be run and shows this error:

$ pytest
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --asyncio

and when i remove my config file, it shows this:

PytestUnhandledCoroutineWarning: async def functions are not natively supported and have been skipped.
You need to install a suitable plugin for your async framework, for example:
- anyio
- pytest-asyncio
- pytest-tornasync
- pytest-trio
- pytest-twisted
warnings.warn(PytestUnhandledCoroutineWarning(msg.format(nodeid)))

But I have installed pytest-asyncio in my environment and it is working fine.

I'm not sure why you've decided to add --asyncio to your options (I've never seen such a parameter before...). But, the other error looks like it's just failing to find the installed plugin.
Also, if we're talking about a web application in aiohttp, then you should be installing pytest-aiohttp as per the documentation:
https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/testing.html
Plus, pytest-asyncio requires a config option to specify if async functions should work without a special decorator:
# pytest.ini
[pytest]
asyncio_mode = auto

https://pytest-asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/configuration.html
